# Neural net not training at all

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, lstm

my neural net accuracy and test loss are stuck while building a model on [HAR](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones). The model was built using only time series variables(expert features were not used)

I have tried many learning rates, and optimizers, even then from epoch 1 to 200 they are stuck at 18% accuracy

The architecture used was from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWMlR8eVgHc&t=983s)
And I couldn't figure out if architecture is really bad or my code has a bug in it.

```
class Net(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.model = nn.ModuleDict({
            'lstm': nn.LSTM(
                input_size=64,    
                hidden_size=64,batch_first=True
            ),
            'linear': nn.Linear(
                in_features=128,
                out_features=6),
            'dropout': nn.Dropout(0.7),
            'lstm2': nn.LSTM(
                input_size=64,    
                hidden_size=128,batch_first=True),
            'linear2': nn.Linear(
                in_features=9,
                out_features=64)})

  def forward(self,x):
    x = x.permute(1,0,2)
    x = x.contiguous().view(-1,9)
    x = self.model['linear2'](x)

    x = x.contiguous().view(-1,128,64)
    x, _ = self.model['lstm'](x)
    x = self.model['dropout'](x)
    x, _ = self.model['lstm2'](x)
    x = self.model['dropout'](x)
    x = self.model['linear'](x[:,-1,:])
    return x


net=Net().to(device)

def train( model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch,):
    model.train()
    train_loss=0
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.view(-1).to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        output = model(data.float())

        train_loss+=F.cross_entropy(output, target).item()
        loss = F.cross_entropy(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    train_loss /= np.ceil(len(train_loader.dataset)/bs)
    print('Train Epoch: {} \tLoss per Batch: {:.6f}'.format(epoch,train_loss))

def test( model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx,(data, target) in enumerate(test_loader):
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data.float())
            test_loss += F.cross_entropy(output, target).item() # sum up batch loss
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True) # get the index of the max log-probability
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()
    test_loss /= np.ceil(len(test_loader.dataset)/bs)


    print('\nTest set: Loss per Batch: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))


import torch.optim as optim
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=.01)
```

---

By using Adam with lr=.01, I got the following results

loss per batch and accuracy of Test set have remained constant during the whole training period of 70 epochs

```
Train Epoch: 0 Loss per Batch: 1.788564

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7989, Accuracy: 533/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 1  Loss per Batch: 1.786124

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 2  Loss per Batch: 1.785584

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7947, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 3  Loss per Batch: 1.785016

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.8117, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 4  Loss per Batch: 1.786215

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7921, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 5  Loss per Batch: 1.785138

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7939, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 6  Loss per Batch: 1.784805

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 7  Loss per Batch: 1.784633

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 8  Loss per Batch: 1.784855

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7938, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 9  Loss per Batch: 1.785028

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7936, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 10     Loss per Batch: 1.784683

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7930, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 11     Loss per Batch: 1.785211

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7930, Accuracy: 527/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 12     Loss per Batch: 1.784648

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7912, Accuracy: 514/2947 (17%)

Train Epoch: 13     Loss per Batch: 1.784625

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7909, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 14     Loss per Batch: 1.785082

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7921, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 15     Loss per Batch: 1.785162

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 509/2947 (17%)

Train Epoch: 16     Loss per Batch: 1.784732

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 17     Loss per Batch: 1.784819

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7949, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 18     Loss per Batch: 1.785135

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7927, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 19     Loss per Batch: 1.784840

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7933, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 20     Loss per Batch: 1.784750

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7939, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 21     Loss per Batch: 1.784810

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7940, Accuracy: 517/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 22     Loss per Batch: 1.784939

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7872, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 23     Loss per Batch: 1.785099

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 24     Loss per Batch: 1.784571

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7918, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 25     Loss per Batch: 1.784607

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7922, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 26     Loss per Batch: 1.784505

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7902, Accuracy: 514/2947 (17%)

Train Epoch: 27     Loss per Batch: 1.785079

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 28     Loss per Batch: 1.784903

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7933, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 29     Loss per Batch: 1.784797

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7938, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 30     Loss per Batch: 1.784668

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7940, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 31     Loss per Batch: 1.784762

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7934, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 32     Loss per Batch: 1.784556

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7947, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 33     Loss per Batch: 1.784983

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 34     Loss per Batch: 1.785202

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7945, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 35     Loss per Batch: 1.785080

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7921, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 36     Loss per Batch: 1.784834

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7925, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 37     Loss per Batch: 1.784711

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7938, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 38     Loss per Batch: 1.784832

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7922, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 39     Loss per Batch: 1.784580

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 40     Loss per Batch: 1.784810

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7928, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 41     Loss per Batch: 1.784549

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7934, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 42     Loss per Batch: 1.784458

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7920, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 43     Loss per Batch: 1.785136

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7974, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 44     Loss per Batch: 1.784797

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7762, Accuracy: 548/2947 (19%)

Train Epoch: 45     Loss per Batch: 1.785898

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7944, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 46     Loss per Batch: 1.784899

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7951, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 47     Loss per Batch: 1.784710

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7934, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 48     Loss per Batch: 1.785024

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7946, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 49     Loss per Batch: 1.784930

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 50     Loss per Batch: 1.784564

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7913, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 51     Loss per Batch: 1.784940

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7936, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 52     Loss per Batch: 1.785000

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7921, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 53     Loss per Batch: 1.784505

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7947, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 54     Loss per Batch: 1.784886

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7914, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 55     Loss per Batch: 1.784894

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7920, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 56     Loss per Batch: 1.784917

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7920, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 57     Loss per Batch: 1.784813

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7941, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 58     Loss per Batch: 1.784905

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7933, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 59     Loss per Batch: 1.784620

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7914, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 60     Loss per Batch: 1.784722

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7934, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 61     Loss per Batch: 1.784789

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7929, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 62     Loss per Batch: 1.784626

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7933, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 63     Loss per Batch: 1.784967

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 64     Loss per Batch: 1.784695

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7918, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 65     Loss per Batch: 1.784872

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7939, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 66     Loss per Batch: 1.784757

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7925, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 67     Loss per Batch: 1.784619

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7912, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 68     Loss per Batch: 1.784919

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7927, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 69     Loss per Batch: 1.784839

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7927, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 70     Loss per Batch: 1.784806

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7937, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 71     Loss per Batch: 1.784729

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7910, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 72     Loss per Batch: 1.784705

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7937, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 73     Loss per Batch: 1.785041

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7936, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 74     Loss per Batch: 1.784568

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7919, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 75     Loss per Batch: 1.784705

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7946, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 76     Loss per Batch: 1.784397

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7896, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 77     Loss per Batch: 1.785445

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 78     Loss per Batch: 1.785322

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 79     Loss per Batch: 1.784972

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7929, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 80     Loss per Batch: 1.785531

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 81     Loss per Batch: 1.784897

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7930, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 82     Loss per Batch: 1.784814

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 536/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 83     Loss per Batch: 1.784614

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7960, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 84     Loss per Batch: 1.785118

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7930, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 85     Loss per Batch: 1.785127

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7919, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 86     Loss per Batch: 1.784900

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7934, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 87     Loss per Batch: 1.784775

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7954, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 88     Loss per Batch: 1.784831

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 89     Loss per Batch: 1.784919

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7937, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 90     Loss per Batch: 1.784544

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 91     Loss per Batch: 1.784984

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7938, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 92     Loss per Batch: 1.784681

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7919, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 93     Loss per Batch: 1.784792

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7928, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 94     Loss per Batch: 1.785022

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7918, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 95     Loss per Batch: 1.785049

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 96     Loss per Batch: 1.784717

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7946, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 97     Loss per Batch: 1.784922

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7912, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 98     Loss per Batch: 1.784669

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7917, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 99     Loss per Batch: 1.784664

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7927, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 100    Loss per Batch: 1.784869

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7937, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 101    Loss per Batch: 1.784915

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7954, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 102    Loss per Batch: 1.784592

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7913, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 103    Loss per Batch: 1.784817

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7920, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 104    Loss per Batch: 1.784869

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7941, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 105    Loss per Batch: 1.787049

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7915, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 106    Loss per Batch: 1.785012

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7919, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 107    Loss per Batch: 1.784757

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7927, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 108    Loss per Batch: 1.784881

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7939, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 109    Loss per Batch: 1.785723

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 110    Loss per Batch: 1.784988

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7914, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 111    Loss per Batch: 1.785197

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7928, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 112    Loss per Batch: 1.784856

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7937, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 113    Loss per Batch: 1.785120

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 114    Loss per Batch: 1.784842

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7906, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 115    Loss per Batch: 1.785119

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7918, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 116    Loss per Batch: 1.784935

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7917, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 117    Loss per Batch: 1.784734

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 118    Loss per Batch: 1.784930

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7916, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 119    Loss per Batch: 1.785058

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 120    Loss per Batch: 1.784399

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7955, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 121    Loss per Batch: 1.784580

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7921, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 122    Loss per Batch: 1.784730

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 123    Loss per Batch: 1.784921

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7946, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 124    Loss per Batch: 1.785217

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7918, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 125    Loss per Batch: 1.784670

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 126    Loss per Batch: 1.784825

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 127    Loss per Batch: 1.785658

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 128    Loss per Batch: 1.785025

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7924, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 129    Loss per Batch: 1.784739

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7949, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 130    Loss per Batch: 1.785050

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 131    Loss per Batch: 1.784816

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7909, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 132    Loss per Batch: 1.784678

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7943, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 133    Loss per Batch: 1.784638

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7934, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 134    Loss per Batch: 1.784962

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7941, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 135    Loss per Batch: 1.784798

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7941, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 136    Loss per Batch: 1.784776

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 137    Loss per Batch: 1.785209

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7908, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 138    Loss per Batch: 1.784884

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 139    Loss per Batch: 1.784842

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 140    Loss per Batch: 1.784622

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7919, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 141    Loss per Batch: 1.785023

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7925, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 142    Loss per Batch: 1.784689

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7944, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 143    Loss per Batch: 1.784810

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 144    Loss per Batch: 1.784905

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7920, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 145    Loss per Batch: 1.784574

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7946, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 146    Loss per Batch: 1.784829

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7930, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 147    Loss per Batch: 1.784832

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7933, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 148    Loss per Batch: 1.784582

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7941, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 149    Loss per Batch: 1.784732

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 150    Loss per Batch: 1.784652

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7947, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 151    Loss per Batch: 1.784722

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 152    Loss per Batch: 1.784994

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7951, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 153    Loss per Batch: 1.784773

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7938, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 154    Loss per Batch: 1.784962

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7934, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 155    Loss per Batch: 1.784522

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7934, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 156    Loss per Batch: 1.784805

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7921, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 157    Loss per Batch: 1.785455

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7944, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 158    Loss per Batch: 1.784509

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7943, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 159    Loss per Batch: 1.784982

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 160    Loss per Batch: 1.784593

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7938, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 161    Loss per Batch: 1.785101

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7930, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 162    Loss per Batch: 1.785277

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7939, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 163    Loss per Batch: 1.784970

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 164    Loss per Batch: 1.784984

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7943, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 165    Loss per Batch: 1.784928

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 166    Loss per Batch: 1.784774

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7923, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 167    Loss per Batch: 1.785107

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 168    Loss per Batch: 1.784620

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7941, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 169    Loss per Batch: 1.784884

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 170    Loss per Batch: 1.784452

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7923, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 171    Loss per Batch: 1.784965

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7935, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 172    Loss per Batch: 1.784781

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7924, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 173    Loss per Batch: 1.784724

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7941, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 174    Loss per Batch: 1.784639

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7912, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 175    Loss per Batch: 1.784592

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7936, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 176    Loss per Batch: 1.784642

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7922, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 177    Loss per Batch: 1.785098

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7931, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 178    Loss per Batch: 1.784758

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7938, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 179    Loss per Batch: 1.784484

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7910, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 180    Loss per Batch: 1.784845

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7949, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 181    Loss per Batch: 1.784970

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7926, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 182    Loss per Batch: 1.785243

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7917, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 183    Loss per Batch: 1.784563

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7932, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 184    Loss per Batch: 1.784880

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7936, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 185    Loss per Batch: 1.784850

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7961, Accuracy: 537/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 186    Loss per Batch: 1.784834

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7921, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 187    Loss per Batch: 1.784880

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7917, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)

Train Epoch: 188    Loss per Batch: 1.784855

Test set: Loss per Batch: 1.7919, Accuracy: 532/2947 (18%)
```

edit1:
Now i have tried to check if params are updating at all as suggested by Ahmad.

````
       x1=net.model.linear2.weight.data # weights at 150 epoch
       x3=net.model.linear2.weight.data # weights at 152 epoch
       x1-x3
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], device='cuda:0')```

So,now i tried to check grad at 152 epoch
net.model.linear2.weight.grad

tensor([[-5.2324e-14, -1.8329e-14, -4.5901e-15,  3.9225e-14, -4.8923e-14,
         -3.7663e-14, -6.6461e-14, -1.3109e-12, -1.4465e-12],
        [ 3.0959e-14,  2.7681e-14, -1.2809e-14, -2.1927e-14,  4.5212e-14,
          3.6410e-14, -1.3647e-13, -1.2680e-12, -1.4908e-12],
        [-7.7439e-15, -1.8330e-14,  1.2772e-14,  4.4520e-15, -2.0769e-14,
         -1.6550e-14,  1.3497e-13,  1.6057e-12,  1.8513e-12],
        [-7.0256e-15, -3.3731e-14,  2.6417e-14,  1.2869e-14, -4.3155e-14,
         -3.2898e-14,  3.1167e-13,  3.5165e-12,  4.0472e-12],
        [ 4.1122e-14,  1.7677e-14,  4.3402e-16, -2.3387e-14,  3.5274e-14,
          2.8663e-14,  3.6638e-14,  6.8818e-13,  7.4608e-13],
        [-7.3279e-14, -3.9648e-14,  6.5658e-15,  4.4829e-14, -7.3947e-14,
         -5.9679e-14,  2.8081e-14, -2.1435e-13, -1.6659e-13],
        [ 3.9702e-15,  1.8115e-14, -1.4382e-14, -1.4078e-15,  1.8547e-14,
          1.5202e-14, -1.5490e-13, -1.8519e-12, -2.1300e-12],
        [ 1.9415e-14,  1.8774e-14, -8.1929e-15, -1.9029e-14,  3.2933e-14,
          2.4555e-14, -9.4528e-14, -8.9978e-13, -1.0555e-12],
        [-9.5713e-15, -3.9856e-14,  3.1216e-14,  1.8188e-14, -5.4189e-14,
         -4.1472e-14,  3.7540e-13,  4.1245e-12,  4.7497e-12],
        [ 6.3520e-15, -6.6954e-15,  7.5276e-15, -1.1499e-16, -5.6589e-15,
         -3.1609e-15,  9.2859e-14,  1.1613e-12,  1.3267e-12],
        [ 2.0287e-14,  1.1300e-14, -2.4096e-15, -1.6815e-14,  2.5231e-14,
          1.9853e-14, -2.9268e-14, -4.7256e-14, -7.8026e-14],
        [-7.6004e-14, -4.6867e-14,  1.1355e-14,  5.1983e-14, -8.6401e-14,
         -6.8230e-14,  9.0062e-14,  4.3427e-13,  5.8239e-13],
        [ 3.0111e-14,  3.5032e-14, -1.8398e-14, -2.6007e-14,  5.4304e-14,
          4.1803e-14, -2.0308e-13, -2.1058e-12, -2.4519e12]],device='cuda:0')

Now i know that this is the case of vanishing gradient.
How should i proceed to remedy vanishing gradients for this architecture??
````

Comment: Where did you initialize the optimizer? Did you check if the parameters get updated after `optimizer.step()`? You have a large dropout in your model. Can you try setting a smaller value (0.2) and see if the training loss goes down?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, i found that the gradients are vanising in the first layers, but i still don't know how to progress with this issue.Thank you for very quick response

Comment: Please do two things. (1) reduce dropout, (2) add a `tanh` after `linear2` layer (after `x = self.model['linear2'](x)`). Also check the gradients in earlier epochs!!

Comment: I reduced the `dropout(0.2)` and also added ` F.tanh ` after `linear2` but the results still remain the same(stuck at 18% accuracy).And i also found that gradients after `epoch 4` are around `1e-5`.